# JS: FormData w/ File Input is Crashing Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, form-data

Got a really odd problem that didn't show up until I pushed my code to a live server and tried to use it with my iPhone.

This is submitting to a node.js script that I've set to log all incoming request (along with headers and methods) and the logs show nothing being received when the problem below presents itself.

So anyway:

```
$('#addrecord').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = '/admin/app/addrecord'
    var data = $('#addrecord')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(data);

            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             cache: false,
             type: "POST", // GET or POST
             url: url, // the file to call
             success: function(response) { // on success..
                if (response.name == 200) {
                    if (response.message == "add") {addComplete(response.address);}
                    else {editComplete(response.address);};
                 }
                 else {
                    console.log("Form Rejected");        
                 }  
              },
              error: function(response) { 
                console.log("Error - " + JSON.stringify(response));
              } 
          });
    });
```

This is paired with the usual `<form id="addrecord" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form"> ... </form>` in my html file.

So the problem is that is this form I have an `<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">` input field. If I try to submit the form without an image selected in this input, the form doesn't send anything and just hangs. Absolutely nothing is received by the server (remember, I'm logging every request).

Now, if I use the file input to select an image off my phone, or if I edit the html to remove the input file field, the Ajax request fires without a hitch and everything is received perfectly by my node.js server.

I'm really stumped on this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a bug in Safari.

Ended up detecting if a file had been selected, and if not, deleting the element from the DOM before submitting the form.